# Schema reference for IIS programmatic administration

Tags: windows, iis, schema

Where can I find the IIS object schema? All I found from MSDN was a picture of the class hierarchy.

To be clear, I want to configure IIS through either WMI or ADSI and I'm looking for something like [the Active Directory schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675085(VS.85).aspx), only for IIS. I want a list of all the objects I can configure, which objects they can be contained in and what their properties are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't point you to a definitive document, you might find this even better: WMI code creator:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&DisplayLang=en

I've used this tool to query IIS WMI objects and it will even script the queries or WMI method calls for you in C# (I used them as examples).

If you run it on a machine with IIS installed, you'll see the root\MicrosoftIISv2 namesspace, which has tons of queryable objects in it, and all their properties and methods.  You are probably looking for something like the IIsWebVirtualDirSetting object - try starting with that as it's got most of the properties you'll see on the IIS config panel.

Comment: Very interesting! The code it produces does not work for me but the code is definitely useful as an example. I'll mark this answer as accepted since it seems unlikely an actual reference that says more than MSDN even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you find some information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa737439.aspx ?

Comment: That documentation seems to be lacking detail in all areas except the IIS7 configuration file, which is exactly what I cannot use, unfortunately.